# Shinydashboard 'topbar'

Tags: r, filter, shiny, shinydashboard

Is it possible to place some items in the horizontal bar next to the `dashboardHeader`? I know you can place `notificationItem` on the far right like in [this example](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html). But I would like to use the same options as in `dashboardSidebar` like adding filters etc. I want such a filter on top:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Pork Chop answer, you can simply use `selectInput` (or other shiny inputs) that you put in a `div` with `float:left` to span horizontally:

```
CustomHeader <- dashboardHeader()
CustomHeader$children[[3]]$children <- list(
  div(style="float:left;height:50px",selectInput("select1", NULL, c("a","b","c"))),
  div(style="float:left;height:50px",selectInput("select2", NULL, c("d","e","f"))))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  CustomHeader,
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(textOutput("text1"),textOutput("text2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text1 <- renderText({input$select1})
  output$text2 <- renderText({input$select2})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 6):

Hi You can do something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

CustomHeader <- dashboardHeader()
CustomHeader$children[[3]]$children <-  div(style="min-width:200px;",tags$input(id="searchbox",placeholder = "  Search...",type="text",class="chooser-input-search",style="width:200px;height:50px;"))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  CustomHeader,
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your example works but on my app I work with an ui.r and server. I get the following error message:
``Error in tagAssert(sidebar, type = "aside", class = "main-sidebar") : 
  Expected tag to be of type aside``

Comment: As you didnt produce an example I made one, if you can post some of the code (so it is reproducible) I can work with that

Comment: I'm so stupid. I forgot to remove the original ``dashboardHeader()``....  Now your example works, thanks. But I'm actually after getting filters like ``selectInput()`` and ``numericInput`` or other shiny functions.. And I see that this just contains a searchbox.

Comment: It is not recommended to post `rm(list = ls())` within your code sample...

Comment: Why isn't recommended? This way the code is fully reproducible

Comment: User might loose unsaved data, at least comment it

Comment: You're the first who complained about this. I will keep that in mind going forward thx

Comment: Then I'm the 2nd to complain. Please remove the `rm(list = ls())`. For now I comment it, but better to eliminate it.